# minSdkVersion of 8 doesn't compile with some needed fields

Tags: android, version, stylesheet, android-2.3-gingerbread

In my android app, we need to support everything from Gingerbread to Jelly Bean. In my stylesheets, I need to have 2 versions of some fields, for example:

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyTheme</item>
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyTheme</item>
```

The issue is that with a minSdkVersion of 8, the "android:" version of the fields don't compile, but without them, the styles don't get applied in the later OS's.

Is there a switch I have to check for in the XML file?

Comment: With what version are you compiling the app?

Comment: Well, I have a minSdkVersion of 8, as I said, and a targetSdkVersion of 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Compile your code against `targetSdkVersion(api 17)`, It will solve the problem.

**Update**

you can create folders in `/res` like  `values`, `values-v11`, `values-v14`, there you can add themes related to different api levels. On device < API 11, theme will be selected from 'values', similarly devices gaving api 11 or above will get theme from 'values-v11' etc

Comment: That is what I am doing. That's the problem. It will compile if I bump up the minSdkVersion, but I can't do that, because I need to include Gingerbread users.